# Which Schema.org tags should I base off for LocalBusiness, Place or Organization?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm a product manager for a local directory. I'm writing some requirements for my developer to update business listing pages with Microdata from Schema.org. Currently we mark up all businesses to `LocalBusiness`.

I can't decide whether we should be using `LocalBusiness` from the `Place` property or `Organization` property? Current listings have `geo` in for geo-coordinates but there are other itemprops I could add.

Is it possible to merge both so I can use `geo` tag inside a `LocalBusiness` that is generally mapped around `Organization`? If so, do I need to define that anywhere in my markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only *one* [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) type. It has *two* parent types, [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) and [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place). It inherits all properties from these parent types (and their parents, up to `Thing`).

You simply provide `http://schema.org/LocalBusiness` as `itemtype`, and you can use an `Organization` property like `founder` and a `Place` property like `geo`:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <div itemprop="founder" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">…</div>
  <div itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">…</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Excellent. Knowing there's inheritance of properties pretty much clears up all confusion. Thank you!